# getting "TypeError: 'function name' is not a function" after parcel build

Tags: javascript, parcel

I'm trying to bundle my npm library with Parcel. Here is a toy version of my code for simplicity.

**directory structure**

```
- dist
 - demo.js
 - demo.map
- src
 - lib
  - lib1.js
 - demo.js
- run.js
```

**demo.js**

```
const {lib1} = require('./lib/lib1')

module.exports = {
  lib1: lib1
}
```

**lib/lib1.js**

```
exports.lib1 = function() {
  return 'hi'
}
```

**run.js**

```
const {lib1} = require('./dist/demo')
console.log(lib1())
```

Here is the build command, which generates `dist/demo.js` and `dist/demo.map`.

```
parcel build src/demo.js -d dist
```

But if I run `run.js`, it will give the following error:

```
console.log(lib1())
            ^

TypeError: lib1 is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/sample/run.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:666:3
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think entry file should be `run.js` instead of `demo.js`